# What in fast food fries have that regular fries don't?

Tags: neuroscience, food

Why is it that a french fry from a fast food restaurant doesn't seem to spoil the same way as one that one would cook at home?

PS: If given enough time will fast food french fries eventually decompose; if so, how long?

Comment: Why did you tag this "neuroscience"? Your question seems to be about preservatives in food. You might be able to get answers if you edit your title and body to make that more clear.

Comment: I suspect you are asking why a fast food fry doesn't spoil?  Water availability...  Read my answer to this post:  https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/57877/19432

Comment: Could trans-fat be a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through a longer winded explanation here:  https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/57877/19432.

In brief, food spoils if water is bio-available to micro-organisms.  In the case of a french fry from say, McDonalds. This fry has a very small volume to surface area ratio, and hence is able to dry out what little water is left after the frying process before micro-organisms can proliferate enough to visibly "spoil" the fry.

If, in your own kitchen, you were take a fresh potato, cut it into fries, and cook them in oil long enough to nearly dehydrate the fry, it would not spoil either in a dry environment.

Take either of those items that had been allowed to cool down and pick up micro-organisms (yeast and bacteria) from the air and place into a sealed ziplock bag with a little water and they would both spoil.

For your last question, in a dry environment, once something has become desiccated, decomposition stops and your fry would only decompose if the environment became more humid.  Think about naturally preserved mummies in an arid environment.

Edit: Light also can break bonds...and lend to further decomposition in the absence of micro-organisms. As can physical abrasion from wind, sand etc... So naturally mummified remains of great age would also have been protected from light and abrasion as well.